# Is there a way to wait for and get a key press from a (remote) terminal session?

Tags: console, keyboard, keypress, telnet, tty

I've been playing around with some ANSI stuff (like colors etc.) in java and php (from scratch) and I'm trying to find a way to basically wait for a key press. I'd like to have something like the following pseudo code at the end of my main event loop:

```
If (KeyPressed)
Begin
    var event = new KeyboardEvent();
        event.Key = ReadKey();
    this.BubbleEvent(event);
End
```

But everything I've been trying over the last couple days fails because the key presses only become available on STDIN after the user has pressed enter.

It doesn't matter much what language you answer in, but `java`, `php`, plain old `c` or `c#` would be nicest, and I cannot use any really spiffy library stuff because I need to port it to all four of those languages... I need this to work over a `telnet` or `ssh` connection, but my research so far suggests it is impossible unless you're working on the local machine.

Please prove me wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The curses function `cbreak(3)` will disable line-buffering and erase/kill handling. You can do this yourself with `stty(1)` if you really want.

When your program dies and leaves the terminal in `cbreak` mode, you can usually use either `stty sane` or `reset` to bring the terminal back to a reasonable state.

From within Perl, you can use either the `Term::ReadKey` or the `Curses` module to manipulate the terminal. See the `Term::ReadKey(3pm)` or `Curses(3pm)` manpage for details.

From within C, you can use either `ioctl(2)` calls on the terminal device to turn on cbreak mode, or you can use curses. See the `ncurses(3)` manpage for details.

Comment: Thanks, this sounds useful. I'll definitely check this out over the weekend!

Comment: So far tough luck, since curses is a lib I cannot (and don't want to) rely on, and I can't figure out how curses does it from reading the source. (and i don't want to learn c++ just to figure this out)

Answer (score 1):

I know, this is an old thread, but I could not find a suitable answer anywhere else. So with some help from the senior programmers of my company I came up with this:

```
private void waitKeypress() throws IOException
{
    System.in.read();
    while ( System.in.available() > 0 ) 
    {
        System.in.read();
    }
}
```

The part reading as much input as is available solved my problem that when used multiple times, "System.in.read()" alone does not always wait.

For me this does the trick, I use it like this:

```
doSomething();
waitKeypress();
doNextThing();
```

Hope it helps.

Kind regards,
Ralph

Comment: While this doesn't fix my problem (I don't want to wait for a key to be pressed) this might be useful for somebody else visiting this thread.