# Stop executing PHP for or while loop in Command line with key press?

Tags: php, command-line-interface

Is it possible in php to exit a loop on a "key press"?

For example continual for loop to exit on key press and to continue executing rest of code so not sigterm, just stop loop and continue?

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is read from stdin:
http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl3_stdin.htm

Here's a tutorial for how to do it in PHP:
http://codegolf.com/boards/conversation/view/129

Hope that helps!

Edit: Found a question which answered this much better: [PHP CLI: How to read a single character of input from the TTY (without waiting for the enter key)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684367/php-cli-how-to-read-a-single-character-of-input-from-the-tty-without-waiting-f)

Comment: Thanks for this. I already tried with STDIN but, you grabbing input stops the script I need something like: while {exec_something; listen for key presss...; if key press occured then leave}

Comment: This question here actually seems to have the answer you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684367/php-cli-how-to-read-a-single-character-of-input-from-the-tty-without-waiting-f

Answer (score 1):

`Ctrl-C` keystroke will stop the loop, I believe ;-)

Comment: Seconded. Just ctrl-c to abort a running php process.

Comment: Ctrl-C is SIGINT. But can't be caught on Windows :(

Answer (score 0):

for Windows, you can use API functions to retrieve keyboard state. The way to call Win32 API functions is described in http://de.php.net/manual/en/ref.w32api.php. The API function you need to call is GetKeyboardState where the result is stored in an array.

Comment: Thanks but I am looking for way to do this on LINUX in command line php script

Answer (score 0):

Press ctrl+pausebreak keys on your keyboard to stop a loop which is running in PHP command shell.